# On the inverse of a symmetric and strictly diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ be an symmetric matrix with positive entries and $0$ on the diagonal, that is,
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots &  a_{1n} \\
a_{12} & 0 & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & 0 &  \cdots &  a_{3n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots \\
a_{1n} & a_{2n} & a_{3n} &  & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

We define the diagonal matrix $D$ whose entries are $d_i = \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij}$ and consider the matrix
$$ B = \alpha \mathrm{Id} + D - A$$
for a real $\alpha > 0$.

$B$ is a matrix with dominant diagonal, and is therefore invertible. I need to show that the inverse $C = (c_{ij})$ of $A$ is such that
$$c_{ii} \geq c_{ij}$$
for any $1 \leq i,j \leq n$.

The result is easily shown to be true for matrices of size $n=2$ for which
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a  \\
a & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},  \quad B =  \begin{bmatrix}
a + \alpha & - a  \\
- a & a + \alpha \\
\end{bmatrix},  \quad 
C  =  \frac{1}{(\alpha + a)^2 - a^2} \begin{bmatrix}
a + \alpha & a  \\
a & a + \alpha \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The case $n=3$ is also simple but I have troubles showing the general case.

(My first attempt was to show the results on the cofactors of $A$, since the comatrix is positively proportional to the inverse, but I could not find a way to simply compare the cofactors.)

Comment: Is $C$ the inverse of $M$ rather than the inverse of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true. In fact, it holds whenever $M$ is a strictly diagonally dominant symmetric M-matrix (or equivalently, when $M$ is a strictly diagonally dominant symmetric $Z$-matrix with a positive diagonal). In your symbols, this means the result holds when $M$ is in the form of $D'+D-A$, where $D$ and $A$ are defined in your way, except that the off-diagonal elements of $A$ are only required to be non-positive (rather than negative) and $D'$ is some positive diagonal matrix (that is not necessarily a positive multiple of $I$). Partition $M$ as
$$
\pmatrix{m_{11}&-v^T\\ -v&S}.
$$
Since $M$ is a strictly diagonally dominant M-matrix, we have $Se-v>0$. However, $S$ is also a strictly diagonally dominant M-matrix. Therefore $S^{-1}$ exists and it is entrywise non-negative. As the dot product of a non-negative and non-zero vector and a positive vector is positive, we have $S^{-1}(Se-v)>0$, i.e., $S^{-1}v<e$. Now, using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix), we obtain
$$
C:=M^{-1}=\pmatrix{(m_{11}-v^TS^{-1}v)^{-1}&\ast\\
(m_{11}-v^TS^{-1}v)^{-1}S^{-1}v&\ast}.
$$
As $M$ is a strictly diagonally dominant M-matrix, it is positive definite. Therefore $c_{11}=(m_{11}-v^TS^{-1}v)^{-1}>0$. As every element of $S^{-1}v$ is smaller than $1$, we conclude that $c_{11}>c_{i1}$ for all $i\ne 1$.

Comment: This seems great! To be sure, the relation $Se - v > 0$ means that $(Se)_i - v_i > 0$ for any i with $e = (1,\ldots,1)$?

Comment: @Goulifet Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The Schur complement argument is cute to finish the job. Thanks a lot.